# Formatting section with titlesec in a custom class

Tags: titlesec

I use the following lines in my preamble to format section inside a colored box:

```
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
    {}
    {0em}
    {\colorbox{mainColor}{
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
    {\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}
```

Output (`\section{Feedback}` with mainColor as `blue!80`):

[image: output]

I am now writing a class file, and I want to use the same style for my section as I always used in my document. However, using the same code in a `.cls` file produce this error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \ttlf@section ^^I^^I{ 
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode
^^I^^I\section{Une section !}
```

The problem is when i try to get the section name with `#1`. I don't know why, but it look like I can't do it in a `.cls` file but it is correct inside a `.tex` file.

Full class file: https://pastebin.com/dQpstaHG

Comment: If you want to use the explicit argument `#1` for the section name in `\titleformat`, you have to load package `titlesec` *with* option `explicit`. But then you have to use `#1` in the `\titleformat` settings for other section level formats too.

Comment: @esdd: Thank you, I have been trying for a whole day to solve this :)